# Programmatically adding StackView not changing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to programmatically set up a stack view. I'm pretty sure I have it all setup correctly but when trying to adjust simple things such as the stack view back ground or align them centrally etc nothing is changing and it's all aligned in the top left.

Here is the code.

ShowGuideViewController:

```
    import UIKit
    import OAStackView

    class ShowGuideViewController: UIViewController {

        let stackView = OAStackView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            ShowGuideItem.all { showGuideItems in
                showGuideItems.forEach(self.viewForShowGuideItem)
            }

            stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
            stackView.distribution = OAStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
            stackView.alignment = OAStackViewAlignment.Center
            stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

            view.addSubview(stackView)


        }

        private func viewForShowGuideItem(showGuideItem: ShowGuideItem) {
            let view = ShowGuideItemView(frame: CGRectZero)
            view.bind(showGuideItem)
            view.tapped = { _ in
                print("Open \(showGuideItem.url)")
            }
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        }


    }
```

Show Guide Item:

```
    import Foundation
    import Freddy

    struct ShowGuideItem {

        let name: String
        let text: String
        let iconFileName: String
        let backgroundImageFileName: String
        let url: String

    }

    extension ShowGuideItem: JSONDecodable {

        init(json: JSON) throws {
            name = try json.string("name")
            text = try json.string("text")
            iconFileName = try json.string("iconFileName")
            backgroundImageFileName = try json.string("backgroundImageFileName")
            url = try json.string("url")
        }

    }

    extension ShowGuideItem {

        static func all(completion: ([ShowGuideItem]) -> ()) {
            let carsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ShowGuide", withExtension: "json")!)!
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data: carsData)
                let items: [ShowGuideItem] = try json.arrayOf("ShowGuideItems")
                completion(items)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to load Show Guide Items")
            }
        }
    }
```

Show Guide Item View:

```
    import UIKit

    class ShowGuideItemView: UIView {

        var nameLabel: UILabel!
        var textBody: UITextView!
        var iconImageView: UIImageView!
        var backGroundImageView: UIImageView!
        var tapped: (ShowGuideItemView) -> () = { _ in }
        private var touched = false

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            setupSubviews()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        func bind(item: ShowGuideItem) {
            nameLabel.text = item.name
            textBody.text = item.text
            iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: item.iconFileName)
            backGroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: item.backgroundImageFileName)
        }


        internal override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            touched = true
        }

        internal override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            if touched {
                touched = false
                tapped(self)
            }
        }

        internal override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            touched = false
        }

        private func setupSubviews() {
            nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
            textBody = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
            iconImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
            backGroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)

            nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            textBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            iconImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backGroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


            addSubview(nameLabel)
            addSubview(textBody)
            addSubview(iconImageView)
            addSubview(backGroundImageView)
        }
    }
```

as you can see it all reads from a json file which I have logged works and outputs correctly as I can see it all overlapping itself when building.

I haven't got to formatting each item in the stackview yet as I wanted to start with centering the stackview itself and aligning it vertically etc.

So, when I add lines like:

```
            stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
            stackView.distribution = OAStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
            stackView.alignment = OAStackViewAlignment.Center
            stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

to viewDidLoad nothing is changing and I can't see why it wouldn't be.

[Current Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siIN0.png)

Comment: What about constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(stackView)

let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:|-[stackView]-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: ["stackView": stackView])

let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "H:|-[stackView]-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: ["stackView": stackView])

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([constraint1, constraint2])

stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
stackView.distribution = OAStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
stackView.alignment = OAStackViewAlignment.Center
stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I put it in and got an initial error: cannot convert value of type [NSLayoutConstraint] to expected element type NSLayoutConstraint. So i added changed the line to NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraint1) and NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraint2) but everything is still aligned in the top left.

Comment: @WayneRumble Does the stackview have the same height and width of its container?

Comment: do you mean doing something like the following: let height = CGFloat(view.bounds.height) , let width = CGFloat(view.bounds.width) , stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: width, height: height) ? Everything i have put in is listed above in the question. I have no storyboard to use due to constraints of the app this is being put into.

Comment: No, I mean: Does your stackView fill the whole container? So, do you see the whole container blue, which is the stackView bg color?

Comment: Sorry, no i dont. The background color doesnt even show. ill put in a screen shot now for you with my code and the code you said to add.

Comment: Screen shot link added at bottom of question

Comment: Can you try calling viewForShowGuideItem after the set of stackView constraints?

Comment: i moved the following below the constraints to no avail:      ShowGuideItem.all { showGuideItems in
            showGuideItems.forEach(self.viewForShowGuideItem)
        }